# Gstreamer warning: error pushing buffer to gstreamer pipeline

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, gstreamer

I am running below Python script but facing issues starting video writer in Opencv.

```
import imutils
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time 

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("video.mp4")  # RTSP URL of USB CAMERA

out = cv2.VideoWriter('appsrc ! videoconvert' + ' ! x264enc speed-preset=ultrafast bitrate=600 key-int-max=40' + \
        ' ! rtspclientsink location=rtsp://192.168.1.18:8554/mystream',
        cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER, 0, int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)), (int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)), int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))), True)
if not out.isOpened():
    print("CANT OPEN VIDEO WRITER")

while True:
    ret, image = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        print("END OF VIDEO")
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 0)
        continue
    image = imutils.resize(image, width=800)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale3(gray, scaleFactor=1.3, minNeighbors=5, minSize=(30, 30), flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, outputRejectLevels=True)
    rects = faces[0]
    weights = faces[2]
    for (x, y, w, h) in rects:
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
        cv2.putText(image, str(weights), (x, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, (0, 0, 255), 1)
    out.write(image)
    cv2.imshow("Frame", image)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if key == ord("q"):
        break
```

I am getting the below issue:

`gstreamer warning: error pushing buffer to gstreamer pipeline`

Opencv is compiled with Gstreamer.

Comment: Why are you posting so much code, when the only relevant part is `out = cv2.VideoWriter('appsrc ! videoconvert' +...`? You are also not telling us what is the error... Make sure your OpenCV is built with GStreamer. Execute `print(cv2.getBuildInformation())` and make sure `GStreamer:                   YES`.  The default is NO. You probably have to build OpenCV from sources with GStreamer enabled.

Comment: @Rotem I thought it will be easy for anyone to quickly try out the whole code instead of writing your own, to save time. :) Opencv has been compiled with Gstreamer.

Comment: OK, so the error is not what I guessed... Still no need to post `CascadeClassifier` stuff.

Comment: @Rotem I thought it will be easy for anyone to quickly try out the whole code instead of writing your own, to save time. :) :)

Comment: Try moving `out.write(image)` up - before `image = imutils.resize(image, width=800)`.

Comment: @Rotem Getting the same error.

Comment: Execute a listener process - GStreamer (or other) process that listen (receive) the RTSP transmission (execute it before starting the Python script). You may test it with localhost (127.0.0.1).

Comment: What if you comment out continue?

Comment: if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break cv2.destroyAllWindows()

Comment: Did you happen to solve?